# Kill the child batch process from parent batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file which is used to trigger a second batch to start another process. The batch scripts run as two different processes in two terminals.

If the first batch process is terminated and run again, we need to first terminate second batch process and then restart it. How can we terminate the second process with the parent batch file?

The current code snippet is as follows. However the termination doesn't happen:

```
tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Server" 2>NUL | find /I /N "Server">NUL

IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (  
    TASKKILL /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Server"  
    timeout /t 120 /nobreak  
    START "Server" "test.bat"  
) ELSE START "Server" "test.bat"
```

Answer (score -1):

This script works well for me:

```
@echo off
tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Server" >nul 2>&1
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (  
    TASKKILL /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Server" >nul 2>&1 
    timeout /t 5 /nobreak  
    START "Server" "test.bat"  
) ELSE (START "Server" "test.bat")
exit /b
```

Comment: The parentheses do not change anything!

Comment: Updated the script, it works well for me. Make sure you have only one open Cmd window with "Server" name.

Comment: If the script works for you and you'll need more help in the future, pls  **Upvote** and **Accept** the answer by clicking both _Arrow Up_ and _Select_ signs to the left of the _Answer Box_. :)